# BODY=null returned from REST call, status = 302

Tags: rest, authentication, resttemplate, http-status-code-302

I am making a REST Api call in my Java application :

```
    RestTemplate restTemplateGES = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    String url = "http://myurl/common/api/usercontext";
    String authToken = "token_value";
    headers.add( "Content-Type", "application/json" );
    headers.add( "Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken );
    HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);

    ResponseEntity<Object> respObject = restTemplateGES.exchange(url,HttpMethod.POST,entity,Object.class);
```

The call returns with Status=302 and Body=null.

When I make exactly the same call from INSOMNIA I am getting a response back in the form of JSON.

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 302 Found redirect status response code indicates that the resource requested has been temporarily moved to the URL given by the Location header. [302 Found](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302)

Comment: ok, but what can I do to avoid it and simulate a call that I make in Insomnia and get a response body back?

Comment: Has the docs say you must look at the headers, you must find the redirect URL. Most probably insomnia read the headers and redirects automatically, you should do it manually.